# javamail: How do I tell gmail not to sign me into chat?

Tags: java, gmail, chat

When I connect to gmail programmatically (using javamail), gmail also automagically signs me into chat. 
How do I tell javamail to tell gmail not to sign me into chat too?

Comment: perfect question for stackoverflow, nice programming puzzle :)

Answer (score 1):

If you manually sign-out of chat once,the next time you login to gmail ,it will retain the previous state,so you can avoid automatic login to chat.There must be a programmatic solution,i'm just giving a temporary solution.

Comment: Thanks Emil, but I'm trying to keep that as a last option